# Java generics, using child class instead of Parent

Tags: java, generics

I have interface

```
interface IAdaptor<T, K>  
{ 
   // ...   
}
```

And I have realisation

```
class AdaptorImpl imlements IAdaptor<SomeClass1, SomeClass1>  
{  
// ...
}
```

Can I use children insted of `SomeClass1`?
something like `class AdaptorImpl imlements IAdaptor<T extends SomeClass1, SomeClass1>`

Comment: What did you try, and what did you find out? Learn to love debugging :)

Comment: I have no idea what this question is asking

Comment: What's the relationship between the interface and the class?

Comment: an interface can only be implemented, so your realisation has nothing to do with the interface? or this is just one big mess of a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume, that you mean

```
class AdaptorImpl implements IAdapter<SomeClass1, SomeClass1>  
{  
    // ...
}
```

I am not sure, what you mean by "children", though. Of course, you can do:

```
class AdaptorImpl<T extends SomeClass1> implements IAdapter<T, SomeClass1>  
{  
    // ...
}
```